# XSLT 1.0 Meunchian grouping

Tags: .net, xslt, xslt-1.0

I find XSLT 1.0 Meunchian grouping very complex. If you can guide me on the following using `xsl:key`, that would be great. The actual XML is huge, and I've only used a partial portion of it to indicate the structure.

If you need any additional clarification please let me know.

My requirement is to have the following sample XML displayed in a tabular format, grouped first by the itemtype name and then by customer name. Please note that the node `Details` has always only one node `Detail`

**Desired Output**

**ItemType   Customer Name      Price**

Book            John Smith         7

DVD         John Smith         45

DVD          Jane Doe          44

**INPUT:**

```
<Item> 
   <SomeRandomField>abc</SomeRandomField>  
  <Details>
    <Detail>
        <Price>7.00</Price
        <CustomerName>John Smith</CustomerName>
     </Detail>
   </Details>
   <ItemType>   
      <Key>1</Key>
      <Name>Book</Name>
   </ItemType>
</Item>

<Item> 
   <SomeRandomField>mno</SomeRandomField>  
  <Details>
    <Detail>
        <Price>45.00</Price
        <CustomerName>John Smith</CustomerName>
     </Detail>
   </Details>
   <ItemType>   
      <Key>2</Key>
      <Name>DVD</Name>
   </ItemType>
</Item> 
<Item> 
   <SomeRandomField>xyz</SomeRandomField>  
  <Details>
    <Detail>
        <Price>44.00</Price
        <CustomerName>Jane Doe</CustomerName>
     </Detail>
   </Details>
   <ItemType>   
      <Key>2</Key>
      <Name>DVD</Name>
   </ItemType>
</Item>
```

Comment: I think you mean sorted, not grouped. You have described a sorting criteria not a grouping criteria. Therefore you do not need Muenchian grouping.

Comment: Did you want html output? or text output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following xslt to transform your xml in order to get desired output, And I have modified your xml by adding `<Items>` root node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Items">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <b>ItemType</b>
        </td>
        <td>
          <b>Customer Name</b>
        </td>
        <td>
          <b>Price</b>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="Item">
       <xsl:sort select="ItemType/Name" order="ascending"/>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="ItemType/Name"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Details/Detail/CustomerName"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Details/Detail/Price"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It lacks sorting and grouping, doesn't it?

Comment: I edited the answer by adding <xsl:sort>, think it will solve the problem.

Comment: @m27 It would be very greatful if you can up vote by clicking up arraow head of the answer ....cheers.........

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following achieves the desired result. The key is used to group by ItemType, you can then include a sort if needed to group the customer names.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Items>
    <Item> 
        <SomeRandomField>abc</SomeRandomField>  
        <Details>
            <Detail>
                <Price>7.00</Price>
                <CustomerName>John Smith</CustomerName>
            </Detail>
        </Details>
        <ItemType>   
            <Key>1</Key>
            <Name>Book</Name>
        </ItemType>
    </Item>

    <Item> 
        <SomeRandomField>mno</SomeRandomField>  
        <Details>
            <Detail>
                <Price>45.00</Price>
                <CustomerName>John Smith</CustomerName>
            </Detail>
        </Details>
        <ItemType>   
            <Key>2</Key>
            <Name>DVD</Name>
        </ItemType>
    </Item> 
    <Item> 
        <SomeRandomField>xyz</SomeRandomField>  
        <Details>
            <Detail>
                <Price>44.00</Price>
                <CustomerName>Jane Doe</CustomerName>
            </Detail>
        </Details>
        <ItemType>   
            <Key>2</Key>
            <Name>DVD</Name>
        </ItemType>
    </Item> 
</Items>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:key name="itemname" match="/Items/Item/ItemType" use="Name"/>
    <xsl:key name="custname" match="/Items/Item/Details/Detail" use="CustomerName"/>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="/Items/Item/ItemType
                    [generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('itemname', Name))]
                    ">
                    <xsl:variable name="local_item" select="Name"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/Items/Item">
                        <xsl:if test="ItemType/Name = $local_item">
                            <p><xsl:value-of select="$local_item"/>-
                                <xsl:value-of select="Details/Detail/CustomerName"/>-
                                <xsl:value-of select="Details/Detail/Price"/></p>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

HTML

```
<html>
   <body>
      <p>Book-John Smith-7.00</p>
      <p>DVD-John Smith-45.00</p>
      <p>DVD-Jane Doe-44.00</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my answer above, I believe for this example a simple sort will also suffice.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
        <xsl:key name="itemname" match="/Items/Item/ItemType" use="Name"/>
        <xsl:key name="custname" match="/Items/Item/Details/Detail" use="CustomerName"/>
        <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <html>
                <body>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/Items/Item">
                        <xsl:sort select="ItemType/Name"/>
                        <xsl:sort select="Details/Detail/CustomerName"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </body>
            </html>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```